# How to count duplicates by multiple records in subtable

Tags: mysql

Say I have the following table structure:

```
products
id | name | price

products_ean
id | product_id | ean
```

A product can (unfortunately) have multiple EAN numbers. Two products can have one or more of the same EAN numbers.

What is the best practice to count the amount of duplicate products by comparing multiple EAN numbers from the products_ean table?

I've tried something like the following, but that makes the query really slower:

```
SELECT
`products`.`name`,
(
SELECT
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  `products_ean`
WHERE
  `ean` IN(
  SELECT
    `ean`
  FROM
    `products_ean`
  WHERE
    `product_id` = `products`.`id`
) AND `products_ean`.`product_id` != `products`.`id`
GROUP BY `product_id`
) AS `ProductEANCount`
FROM
`products`
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: Are you trying to find those ean values which exist in multiple product(s) ? Some sample data and expected output would really be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using joins is the simplest way to generate related information. I've `GROUP BY` the product.id which means the `eans` are the aggregated field because those are the only ones that can duplicate. I've added `HAVING` part after the query to select only those results with 2 or more (its optional).

```
SELECT p.id, name, price, count(ean) as eans
FROM products p
JOIN products_ean e
  ON p.id = e.product_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING eans >= 2
```

On query efficiency, having the product_id,ean as a composite primary key for the `products_ean` table is probably most efficient. Since that is unique its not obvious why the `products_ean.id` column is needed.

Comment: I guess OP is trying to find those `ean` values which exist in multiple product(s) ?

Comment: I didn't read it that way, however the output wasn't specified. `GROUP_CONCAT(ean) as ean_list` could be added to the `SELECT` results.

Comment: maybe other way around; group_concat(product_id) and group by on ean. But i would wait for OP to clarify further.

Comment: The query works, but unfortunately it is still really slow (14 secs). 

To clarify some uncertainties:
1) 1 product will never have the same EAN in the products_ean table (so product_id + ean is unique)
2) I don't wish to retrieve the EANS that have been found, just the count is enough

I have a unique index on `product_id`+`ean`, and a regular index on `ean`.

One (pretty) important field I forgot to mention is the 'webshop_id'. Products will also not have the same EAN with the same webshop_id (sorry I forgot to mention this earlier)

Comment: @danblack one optimization I can think of is changing `left join` to `join`. OP has clarified. so +1

Comment: On slowness, it does have to walk though both tables. `EXPLAIN {query}` will show you indexes used. Include `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tbl}` for items, easier and more concise than text descriptions. the mysql version will affect the range of optimizations available.